# UBER loading action ? Are they using GIF/ Video

Tags: ios, objective-c, gif, loader, uiactivityindicatorview

**Uber** has currently updated its app with few changes like a **`new app icon`** and adding a **`LOADER SCREEN`** between the `splash screen` and `first view controller` inorder to fetch the location of the user and send it to the server.

> Hierarchy will be like this
>
> - Splash Screen
> - Loader Screen - inorder to send the user's accurate current location    to server
> - First Screen

How to implement this loading action ? Are they using GIF/ Video... Help me to implement the same..

Attached an image of it.

[image]